# Is AMD GPU FirePro support enough for Linux's Matlab and CUDA?

Tags: graphics, gpu, matlab

I need GPU with CUDA support and open-source community support for FFT computation with Matlab R2015b. I think I need to reject nVidia GPUs because of bad open-source support, [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MShbP3OpASA&t=49m57s) Torvalds about nVidia's open-source development. 
So I am thinking some AMD GPU's which has a development plan for open-source support of CUDA, [here](http://www.amd.com/en-us/press-releases/Pages/boltzmann-initiative-2015nov16.aspx) press release. 
I need to do GPU computation because my system's RAM (16 GB/32 GB) is fully utilized in the computation process. 
I plan to split all FFT computationt into GPU, which the documentation says should be possible [here](http://se.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-gpu.html).

Is AMD GPU FirePro support enough yet for Linux's Matlab and CUDA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Otoy's reversed-engineered solution, discussed [here](http://venturebeat.com/2016/03/09/otoy-breakthrough-lets-game-developers-run-the-best-graphics-software-across-platforms/). 
Some limitations can exist as discussed in some threads about the topic.